# WinAPI. Кнопка внутри TabControl

Tags: winapi

Создаю по примеру документации TabControl

```
HWND DoCreateTabControl(HWND hwndParent)
{
    INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX icex;

    TCITEM tie;
    TCHAR image[]   = L"Image";
    TCHAR contour[] = L"Сontour";
    TCHAR square[]  = L"Square";
    TCHAR hatch[]   = L"Hatch";


    icex.dwSize = sizeof(INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX);
    icex.dwICC = ICC_TAB_CLASSES;
    InitCommonControlsEx(&icex);

    hwndTab = CreateWindow(WC_TABCONTROL, global::drawwz,WS_CHILD | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | WS_VISIBLE,0,45, WS_MAXIMIZE, WS_MAXIMIZE, global::hwnd,(HMENU)IDM_TABCONTROL,global::hInst, NULL);

        tie.mask = TCIF_TEXT;// | TCIF_IMAGE;
        tie.iImage = -1;

        tie.pszText = image;
        TabCtrl_InsertItem(hwndTab, 0, &tie);
        tie.pszText = contour;
        TabCtrl_InsertItem(hwndTab, 1, &tie);
        tie.pszText = square;
        TabCtrl_InsertItem(hwndTab, 2, &tie);
        tie.pszText = hatch;
        TabCtrl_InsertItem(hwndTab, 3, &tie);




    return hwndTab;
}



HWND DoCreateDisplayWindow(HWND hwndTab)// Окно внутри Tab
{
    HWND hwndStatic = CreateWindow(WC_STATIC, L"",WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER,30,30, global::DisplayWidht, global::Displayheigth, hwndTab, NULL,global::hInst, NULL);


    return hwndStatic;
}



//Две кнопки внутри этого окна
CreateWindowW(L"BUTTON", L"Open Proect", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, (global::DisplayWidht / 2) - 200, (global::Displayheigth / 2) - 100, 420, 50, arg, (HMENU)IDM_FILE_OPEN, global::hInst, NULL);
        CreateWindowW(L"BUTTON", L"Open Image", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, (global::DisplayWidht / 2) - 200, (global::Displayheigth / 2), 420, 50, arg, (HMENU)IDM_FILE_OPEN, global::hInst, NULL);
```

Проблема в том, что кнопки не работают. Не создают никаких событий, хотя и отображаются. Как сделать чтоб кнопки работали?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как я понял, вы создаете кнопку, указывая в качестве родительского hwndStatic, поэтому сообщения от кнопки приходят не вашему окну, а окну hwndStatic. 
Вам следует ловить сообщения от кнопки в WndProc её родительского окна.

Варианты:

1. Зарегистрировать собственный класс окна со своей собственной процедурой WndProc. Создать дочернее окно на основе этого класса. На него положить кнопки.
2. Создать дочернее окно на основе диалога из ресурсов, на него положить кнопки, и обрабатывать нажатие кнопки в DialogProc.

При этом рекомендуется, чтобы страница таб контрола лежала не на самом таб контроле, а на родительском окне.